# Why does the modulus not help to find negative odd number?

Tags: java, arrays, modulus

**What I am doing:** Replacing odd numbers(values) in array with zeros.
**Problem:** when executing following code it replaces only *positive* numbers, ignoring *negative*.
**Code**:

```
    public static int[] nullOddValues(int[] array) {

        int[] resultArray = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
                resultArray[i] = 0;
            } else {
                resultArray[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        return resultArray;
    }
```

Comment: I don't get the question. You are setting array elements with odd index to zero. How can an array index be negative?

Comment: Going off of Henry, did you mean to do if (array[i] % 2 != 0) ?

Comment: @Henry, my mistake, I edited the code. I am replacing Odd Values with zero.

Comment: @Ryan, yes, exactly. I did a mistake in code.

Comment: This code works for me :/

Comment: @Bohemian with negative values in your array?

Comment: @Victor yes. I just copy-pasted this code and called it with `{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}` and got back `[0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]` as expected.
`

Comment: see https://ideone.com/pqwOxe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test the loop variable `i` for oddity when you (probably) want to test  `array[i]`

```
if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
```

Comment: Yes, I edited the code. But the problem still remains. It's not replacing negative values with zero.

Comment: @Victor do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using modulus on X returns `[0-X)`

- positive X (X > 0) -> it will return 0+
- negative X (X < 0) -> it will return 0-

For your problem, I recommend using a bit operator

```
if((i & 1) == 0)
```

This will return `true` for even numbers (positive and negative), since it is checking the last bit of the number.

Comment: You need parentheses around `i & 1` here. Also `x % 2 != 0` already works for negative numbers, -1 is also not equal to 0.

Comment: Fixed, was testing in System.out.println

Comment: The bitwise operator may be more useful for checking odds than evens, as one could run into attempting to use i % 2 == 1 and not work on negatives

Comment: I'd say the bitwise option is safer in general yes (also I didn't downvote, but I'm not convinced it's worth my upvote either..)

Comment: I like the mentioning of the bit operator alternative, that is safer in general.